# Unable to see term set when I try to add Managed Metadata column in list

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata

I am unable to see term set when I try to add Managed Metadata column in list. It shows blank, but when I see in central admin I can see term set there.

I tried this link, but it didn't helped.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2439274

This is what I see when I try to add column in SharePoint list:
[image]

This is screenshot from central admin
[image]

Is I am missing some settings?

**Update 1**

I checked another web application on same server, where I am able to see the terms when I try to create Managed Metadata column in list.

But this particular web-application, doesn't show the term set while creating Managed Metadata column.

Comment: Instead of seeing in Central Admin site, Can you find the term set in the root site collection?

Comment: Hi Asad, I am at root site collection only. Also the old managed metadata columns shows the data in list view, but when i open edit form the field appears blank.

Comment: Also when i open edit form, a error pop-up comes which says, The server method 'VaildateTerms' failed

Comment: You can give it  a try `Enable-SPFeature –id "73EF14B1-13A9-416B-A9B5-ECECA2B0604C" –Url <SiteURL>`.

Comment: What is this powershell about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found below link which helped me to resolve the issue.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ketaanhs/archive/2012/04/04/the-server-method-validateterms-failed-on-editprofile-page.aspx

The below handler entry was missing from my web.config file of web application:

```
<add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" 
preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I checked the previous copy of web config and it was there, not sure how it got removed from current copy of web config.